# С++: приведение типов

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, перегрузка-операторов, c++14

Подскажите пожалуйста один вопросик (что-то совсем из головы вылетело):

сделал такой класс:

```
class seconds_t
{
protected:
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::seconds::period> value;

public:
    operator std::string() const;
};

seconds_t::operator std::string() const
{
    return std::to_string(value.count());
}
```

и хочу, чтобы можно было задавать 2 типа значений (`double` и `std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::seconds::period>`)

```
const seconds_t t1 = 11.2; // задал double - перевелось в секунды
const seconds_t t2 = 2h;   // задал через суффиксы времени
```

вот как это сделать можно?

Comment: Написать конструкторы и/или `operator=`

Comment: Можно сделать через два конструктора преобразования (не `explicit`). Один принимает `double`, второй `std::chrono::..`. Инициализация переменных в классах соответствующая.

Comment: @ Andrej Levkovitch, не очень понял, поясните пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```
class seconds_t
{
seconds_t();
seconds_t(std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::seconds::period>);
seconds_t(double a)
~seconds_t();
protected:
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::seconds::period> value;

public:
    operator std::string() const;
};

seconds_t::operator std::string() const
{
    return std::to_string(value.count());
}
```